# Add custom information in editor summary

Tags: customization, custom-field, visual-editor

I made a custom meta data to my posts by using

```
register_meta( 'post', 'my-custom-field', [
        'object_subtype' => 'post',
        'type' => 'string',
        'single' => true,
]);
```

That works perfectly but now, I would like to display this data in the editor summary

[image]

If anyone has an idea on how to do it, it would be nice !
Thank you :)

Comment: are you asking how to add a field to the sidebar, or, are you saying you know how to do that but don't know how to show it in the summary specifically? Note that classic editor metaboxes still show up in that sidebar so the metabox API is still fine but it will show up as its own panel underneath, it won't show up inside the summary panel

Comment: I don't know how to do it in either case :(
I would love to have it in the summary but it can be somewhere else in that sidebar
The metadata I try to display in this sidebar is a text and is common to all the posts type (custom included).

Answer (score 0):

Please try by using this method. https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/slotfills/plugin-post-status-info/

```
import { registerPlugin } from '@wordpress/plugins';
import { PluginPostStatusInfo } from '@wordpress/edit-post';

const PluginPostStatusInfoTest = () => (
    <PluginPostStatusInfo>
        <p>Post Status Info SlotFill</p>
    </PluginPostStatusInfo>
);

registerPlugin( 'post-status-info-test', { render: PluginPostStatusInfoTest } );
```

[image]

I hope, this will works for you.